# How to set grouped TextField value to the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm building a website with react. I create a component which has grouped Textfield , I don't know how to set the value of those Textfield to the state.
The state format should be like : `state:{products:[{},{},{}]}`

I've tried to create a button to insert new group of Textfield, and an handleChange method to capture the Textvalue,
but still stuck in how to set states.

```
export default class extends Component {
    state = {
        count: 0,

        products: []
    };

    handleAddClick = () => {
        this.setState(({count}) => ({
            count: count + 1
        }))
    };

    handleChange = e => {
        //this is where i stuck
    };

    render() {
        const {count} = this.state;
        let items = [];
        for (let i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
            items.push(
                <div key={i}>
                    <TextField
                        label="product"
                        margin="normal"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <TextField
                        label="color"
                        margin="normal"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <TextField
                        label="quantity"
                        margin="normal"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                    <TextField
                        label="price"
                        margin="normal"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
            )
        }
        return <Fragment>
            <Button onClick={this.handleAddClick}>
                <AddIcon/>
            </Button>
            {items}
        </Fragment>
    }
}
```

I realize that I have to use some id to identify the different group of TextFields, but where to put it , and how to get it in handleChange method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state seems wrong, you need add one more key which handles input changes, lets call it as `product`. So, this product will handle the current textboxes and once user click add button you can add that to your products array. this produce will an object.

```
state = {
  count: 0,
  product:{},
  products: [],
};
```

pass the textfield value with keys so you can fill the product object key,

```
<TextField value={this.state.product.product}
   label="product"
   type="text"
   margin="normal"
   onChange={(e) => { this.handleChange(e, 'product') }}
 />
```

And set it like  this

```
handleChange = (e, type) => {
  this.setState({ 
    product: { 
      ...this.state.product, 
      [type]: e.target.value, 
    },
  });
};
```

And when user clicks on add you can push this produce to products array

```
handleAddClick = () => {
  this.setState({ 
    products: this.state.products.concat(this.state.product), 
    product: {}, 
  })
};
```

Here is how your component will look:

**Replace input with `TextField` and button with `Button`**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
    product: {},
    products: [],
  };

  handleAddClick = () => {
    this.setState({ 
      products: this.state.products.concat(this.state.product), 
      product: { 
        product: "",
        color: "",
        quantity: "",
        price: "",
      }
    })
  };

  handleChange = (e, type) => {
    //this is where i stuck
    this.setState({ 
      product: { 
        ...this.state.product, [
          type]: e.target.value, 
      } 
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    const { count } = this.state;
    let items = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
      items.push(
        <div key={i}>
          <input value={this.state.product.product}
            label="product" type="text"
            margin="normal"
            onChange={(e) => { this.handleChange(e, 'product') }}
          />
          <input value={this.state.product.color}
            label="color"
            margin="normal"
            onChange={(e) => { this.handleChange(e, 'color') }}
          />
          <input value={this.state.product.quantity}
            label="quantity"
            margin="normal"
            onChange={(e) => { this.handleChange(e, 'quantity') }}
          />
          <input value={this.state.product.price}
            label="price"
            margin="normal"
            onChange={(e) => { this.handleChange(e, 'price') }}
          />
        </div>
      )
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleAddClick}>
          add
        </button>
        {items}
      </div>
    )
  }
}



render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**EDIT:**

As you want to iterate over products and change the values,You do not need product any more we will use the product as base values for the products, now following things will be changed, you need to get index of each products and by default we will assign one value

like this

```
let product = { 
  product: "",
  color: "",
  quantity: "",
  price: "",
};
class App extends Component {
  state = {   
    products: [Object.assign({},product)],
  };

  handleAddClick = () => {  
    var newProduce = {
      product: "", 
      color: "", 
      quantity: "", 
      price: "", 
    }    
    this.setState({ 
      products: this.state.products.concat(newProduce),
    })
  };

  handleChange = (e, type, index) => {
    const copiedData = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    copiedData.products[index][type] = e.target.value;    
    this.setState(copiedData);
  };
  ...
```

[Here is the demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mr1mml)

Comment: this code works fine when user type follow a sequence,but what if user click add button first,and then type. how to modify the corresponding element of the products array

Comment: @Russell for that you need to put the initial values in state, `state = {
    count: 0,
    product: { product: "", color: "", quantity: "", price: "" },
    products: []
  };` like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mr1mml

Comment: The add button is to create new group of TextField , so that why i need the count state, and I also define the items array in the render method,when user click the add button ,they actually get 4 More TextField each time

Comment: your code perfectly solve my problem, thanks a lot !

Comment: @Russell glad that helped